# how to prevent annoying float concatenation

Tags: javascript

I have a function in one of my projects that does some vector calculations. Recently I started noticing inconsistencies in the results and when I went digging, I found out that in some places, JavaScript would perform a concatenation instead of an addition. Upon searching I found that you could prevent it by adding a `parsefloat()` to ensure the variables are float. So now I have this :

```
function getsqSegDistID(p, p1, p2) {
    var x = parseFloat(p1.x),
        y = parseFloat(p1.y),
        dx = p2.x - x,
        dy = p2.y - y;
    if (dx !== 0 || dy !== 0) {
        var t = (parseFloat((p.x - x) * dx) + parseFloat((p.y - y) * dy)) / (parseFloat(dx * dx) + parseFloat(dy * dy));
        if (t > 1) {
            x = p2.x;
            y = p2.y;
        } else if (t > 0) {
            x = parseFloat(x) + parseFloat(dx * t);
            y = parseFloat(y) + parseFloat(dy * t);
        }
    }
    dx = p.x - x;
    dy = p.y - y;
    return parseFloat(dx*dx) + parseFloat(dy*dy);
}
```

**See all the `parseFloat` I put in there ?**

So My issue is that adding a parsefloat before every addition has brought down the performance of the function significantly. This now takes 5x more time to execute than it previously did.

**1.** Do I have to put a parseFloat before every addition? or is there a better way?

**2.** I am a C/Java developer, but I'm helping out a friend to write some processing logic. So *why the heck* doesn't JavaScript have some form of datatype enforcement?

Comment: Regarding types: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system . The answer to (2) simply is: Because it doesn't. It's a different language that is differently designed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. JavaScript will attempt concatenation if one or more of the operands is a string. You certainly don't need to call `parseFloat` every single time, just make sure you call it on all of your passed variables. I see you initially parse `p1.x` and `p1.y`, but don't do the same for the values in `p` or `p2`.
2. JavaScript is an interpreted language, and is therefore dynamically-typed. Statically-typed languages must be compiled; it's just one of many tradeoffs in language design.